# Where should I save the Amazon Manifest json file on an app hosted at PythonAnywhere?

Tags: json, pythonanywhere

I am trying to have my app on Amazon appstore. 
In order to do this Amazon needs to park a small json file (web-app-manifest.json).

If I upload it to the the root of my web site (as suggested), Amazon bot says it cannot access file. Amazon support mention I should save it to /var/www/static but either I don't know how to get there or I don't have access to this part of the server.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get to /var/www/static in the File browser. Just click on the '/' in the path at the top of the page and then follow the links.

You can also just copy things there from a Bash console.

You may need to create the static folder in /var/www if it's not there already.

Comment: I found the little "/" (THANKS!)....went to www folder and created the static folder under it.Uploaded the manifest ...json file from  amazon to this newly created folder

Reloaded the application

Same issue remains : "Server did not allow us to access the manifest" 

Can it be that Amazon doesn't have permission to access that part of the server ?

Comment: For anyone else reading this, it worked when Toren used the right URL for his manifest.

Answer (score 1):

Ok...After some clarifications from PythonAnywhere and Amazon support, this what worked for me:

Assume:
The name of website is XYZ.
One accesses the web site at: https://XYZ.pythonanywhere.com/XYZ/default/index

Amazon json file is parked at https://XYZ.pythonanywhere.com/web-app-manifest.json
Which on the file system at PythonAnywhere translates to:
/var/www/static/web-app-manifest.json

Amazon support asked me to add to this json file the following snippet:
"launch_path":"XYZ/default/index",

Now Amazon bot can access the manifest file and authenticate my relationship with it for the Amazon appstore.